# HTML div out of position when browser window changes

Tags: html, css

I'm just wondering what do we need to add into our coding so that my div position will auto adjust according to the browser's window size? Currently my div and input box always run out of position whenever I reduce the size of my browser's window.

Below is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function startTime()
        {
            var today=new Date();
            var y=today.getFullYear();

            document.getElementById('datetime').innerHTML="&#169; Systems 2003-"+y+"<br>"+"All rights reserved.";
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #username{
            position:absolute;
            top:190px;
            left:70px;
        }
        #login{
            position:absolute;
            top:260px;    
            left:545px;
        }
        #password{    
            position:absolute;
            top:240px;    
            left:70px;
        }

        #box{
            border:1px solid #eaeaff;
            background-color: #eaeaff;
            border-radius:5px;
            width:400px;
            height:400px;   
            margin-top:100px;
            margin-left:360px;
            box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px black;
        }
        .btn{
            height: 30px;
            width: 100px;
            position:absolute;
            top:395px;    
            left:620px;
        }
        #logo{
            position:absolute;
            top:130px;    
            left:595px;
        }
        #model{
            font-size: 25px;
            position:absolute;
            top:200px;    
            left:545px;
        }
        #datetime{
            margin-top:20px;
        }   
    </style> 
</head>
<body onload="startTime()">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="box">
            <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" id="logo"/>
            <div id="model"><p>Welcome</p></div>
            <div id="login"><p>Please login</p></div>
            <form class="form-signin">
                <div class="col-md-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username"></div>
                <div class="col-md-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password"></div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="datetime" align="center">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: why are you using `position:absolute` for the inputs?

Comment: I thought of fixing the position of the inputs. Any idea to improve it?

Comment: When positioning most elements absolute they should always have a parent of position relative. unless you want all hell to break loose.

Comment: Then does that means my #box div should have a position:relative?

Comment: This should be tagged 'twitter-bootstrap'--its bootstrap markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step One:** Remove your absolutely positioned CSS stuff.

**Step Two:** Take a look at [this demo bootply](http://www.bootply.com/AyqUzOtHbv) with this markup in it:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="box" class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
            <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" id="logo">
            <div id="model">
                <p>Welcome</p>
            </div>
            <div id="login">
                <p>Please login</p>
            </div>
            <form class="form-signin">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            </div>
            </form>
            <div id="datetime" align="center">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Step Three:** Become more familiar with [how Bootstraps grid works.](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

HTH :)

Comment: thanks! I have tried your code. But the #box is not at the center of the page. Any idea?

Comment: If you can use CSS3 use `position:absolute; transform: translate(-50%, -50%; left: 50%; top: 50%;` on the `#box`

Comment: Sorry. It's my fault. Now my #box are on the center of the page already.

Comment: How do we let the #box move to the left of the window every time we reduce the size of the window? Now it is fixed to center only and when I adjust the window size to smaller, it hide the #box.

Comment: @Coolguy just remove the `.col-sm-offset-3` class to have it left alilgned. Really spend a little time reading that linked page on how the bootstrap grid works, and mess around with the linked bootply to see how removing the offset class changes things.

Comment: @Coolguy heres [another bootply](http://www.bootply.com/4yTgfViVA0), that uses your styles on top of bootstraps built in styles, and left aligns it. Please, please, please use a bootstrap solution and not a solution that simply overrides all that bootstrap is giving you.

Comment: @Ted what I mean is when the window is full screen, the #box will be in center. But when I reduce the size of the window, it will adjust itself and still be in center of the window. Currently when I reduce the window size, it will hide the #box.

Comment: So you want it to be centered, and not hide? Or do you want it to hide on small screens?

Comment: @Ted. I don't want it to be hide. I want it to be center when I reduce the window size.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74208/discussion-between-ted-and-coolguy).

Answer (score 0):

you dont need all those position absolutes. Replace your CSS with this: [**HERES A DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/t61a56cd/)

```
#box {
    border:1px solid #eaeaff;
    background-color: #eaeaff;
    border-radius:5px;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    margin:100px auto;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px black;
    text-align:center;
}

.btn {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
}

#model {
    font-size: 25px;
}
#datetime {
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic solution without bootstrap: Remember only use absolute positioning when you absolutely have to.

**Note:** *If you intended for your login text inputs to be pushed off to the side, this works. However as far as UX goes this is probably a very bad idea.*

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function startTime()
        {
            var today=new Date();
            var y=today.getFullYear();

            document.getElementById('datetime').innerHTML="&#169; Systems 2003-"+y+"<br>"+"All rights reserved.";
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
  html, body{
   height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;
  }
        #box{
            border:1px solid #eaeaff;
            background-color: #eaeaff;
            border-radius:5px;
            width:400px;
            height:400px;   
            box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px black;
   text-align:center;
        }
        .btn{
            height: 30px;
            width: 100px;
        }
        #model{
            font-size: 25px;

        }
        #datetime{
            margin-top:20px;
        }   
  .form-control{
   margin:10px;
  }
  
  .form-container{
   width:25%;
   height:500px;
   float:left;
   min-width:185px;
   
  }
  .container{
   height:500px;
   width:100%;
  }
  #box-container{
   width:48%;
   height:500px;
   float:left;
  }
  #box2{
            width:400px;
  }
  #form-signin1{
   position: relative;
   top: 35%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
    </style> 
</head>
<body onload="startTime()">  
    <div class="container">
  <div class="form-container">
   <form id ="form-signin1" class="form-signin">
    <div class="col-md-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password"></div>
   </form>
  </div>
  
  <div id="box-container">
   <div id="box">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" id="logo"/>
    <div id="model"><p>Welcome</p></div>
    <div id="login"><p>Please login</p></div>
    
    <form class="form-signin">
     <button class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </form>
   </div>
   <div id="box2">
    <div id="datetime" align="center"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

Something like this?

[Fiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/1jktpzxm/)

```
   #box {
       border:1px solid #eaeaff;
       background-color: #eaeaff;
       border-radius:5px;
       width:300px;
       height:400px;
       margin-top:100px;
       margin-left:360px;
       box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px black;
       padding: 3em 4em;
   }
   #box form, #box header {
       text-align: right;
   }
   #box .form-group {
       margin-bottom: 15px;
       /*boostrap will already have this so delete it */
   }
   .btn {
       height: 30px;
       width: 100px;
   }
   #model {
       font-size: 25px;
              }
   #datetime {
       margin-top:20px;
   }

<div class="container">
   <div id="box">
    <header>
        <img src="logo.png" alt="logo" id="logo" />
         <h2 id="model">Welcome</h2>

        <p>Please login</p>
    </header>
    <section>
        <form class="form-signin">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </form>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div id="datetime" align="center"></div>
```

Comment: I didn't vote you down, but your example gets pushed off the page when resized.